# Error using logout link with Devise Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I'd like to start off saying I know there are other questions on here about this however none of them are using rails 4 and I could not get their suggestions to work. The error I am getting is "uninitialized constant HomeController"

code in index.html.erb

```
<%if user_signed_in? %>
    <p align= "right">Hello <%=current_user.email %> <%= link_to "sign out", destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete %></p>
```

Here are the first 3 lines to application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
```

I'm thinking it might have something to do with this line in my routes.rb file

```
root 'home#index'
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: That last chunk of code is just used to say that if you are the person who created the post than you can delete it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in my routes.rb file it should have read 'posts#index' instead of 'home#index"

Answer (score 0):

you dont have home controller at app/controllers/

you should create app/controllers/home_controller.rb with:

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end
end
```

for your second error:
you call method email for nil(not post).

Comment: now I'm getting this error "NoMethodError in Posts#index"

Comment: can you put all logs? Usually it means that you try to call undefined method

Comment: forgive me I'm very new to rails. I'm not quite sure what all logs means

Comment: When I comment out the if statement I now have routing error saying "uninitialized constant HomeController"

Comment: "NoMethodError in Posts#index" "undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass" it is what i want. You call method email for nil

Comment: is that all, because the logout link is still broken?

Comment: for logout link add home controller.

Comment: somewhere in here? <%= link_to "sign out", destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete %>